# Error can't find the y.position variable 'y.position' in the data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot significant values in ggplot boxplot I am getting error unable understand why this error is comming

my data

```
structure(list(data1 = c(0.05, 0.068, 0.063, 0.075, 0.047), 
      data2 = c(-0.029,-0.011,0.009,0.117,0.116), 
      data3 = c(-0.048,-0.030,-0.026,-0.049,-0.087), 
      data4 = c(-0.070,-0.072,-0.035,-0.001,-0.021)), 
      class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

code I used

```
library(reshape)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

regcovMat <- read.table("Test.txt", sep="\t", header=T)
molten.data <- melt(regcovMat)
stat.test <- compare_means(
  value ~ variable, data = molten.data,
  method = "t.test"
)

data=ggplot(molten.data, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=variable)) + 
  geom_boxplot()+theme_cowplot()+theme(legend.position = "top")
data + stat_pvalue_manual(stat.test, label = "p")
```

Can anyone suggest me to resolve the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
check <- structure(list(data1 = c(0.05, 0.068, 0.063, 0.075, 0.047), 
               data2 = c(-0.029,-0.011,0.009,0.117,0.116), 
               data3 = c(-0.048,-0.030,-0.026,-0.049,-0.087), 
               data4 = c(-0.070,-0.072,-0.035,-0.001,-0.021)), 
          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

check2 <- check %>% 
  pivot_longer(., cols = everything()) 

stat.test <-  compare_means(
    value ~ name, data =check2,
    method = "t.test")
stat.test =stat.test[1,]

ggplot(check2) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = name, y = value, fill = name)) +
  stat_pvalue_manual(stat.test, label = "p", y.position = 0.15, step.increase = 0.2) +
  theme_cowplot() +
  scale_fill_viridis(option="plasma",discrete = T) +
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, is it possible show only one p-value like data1 vs data2 hide rest of the comparision in the same plot?

Comment: yes I have edited the answer accordingly. Please upvote if you agree, and many kudos to danloo as well

Comment: Yup I will upvote both the ansr Thanks a lot

Comment: can you please mentioned on what bases you kept y.position=15

Comment: you have to play around a bit with it, the y.position column containing the coordinates (in data units) to be used for absolute positioning of the label. Default value is "y.position". Can be also a numeric vector.

Answer (score 5):

```r
library(reshape)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(cowplot)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'cowplot'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:ggpubr':
#> 
#>     get_legend
#> The following object is masked from 'package:reshape':
#> 
#>     stamp

regcovMat <- structure(list(data1 = c(0.05, 0.068, 0.063, 0.075, 0.047), data2 = c(-0.029, -0.011, 0.009, 0.117, 0.116), data3 = c(-0.048, -0.030, -0.026, -0.049, -0.087), data4 = c(-0.070, -0.072, -0.035, -0.001, -0.021)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

molten.data <- melt(regcovMat)
#> Using  as id variables
stat.test <- compare_means(
  value ~ variable,
  data = molten.data,
  method = "t.test"
)

ggplot(molten.data) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  stat_pvalue_manual(stat.test, label = "p", y.position = 0.15, step.increase = 0.2) +
  theme_cowplot() +
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: thanks can you suggest me based on what you kept y.position=0.15

Comment: Thats a very nice one. Very good job I was mid way when you poster the answer

Comment: @LDT Thanks. Stack overflow is always a race :D

Comment: @danlooo I do not know wether you can have a glimpse to the post I've publishhed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69899642/how-to-create-by-an-iterative-method-a-series-of-boxplots-with-statistics-annota. I think the solution you've pubblished may fit my case, but do not know how to iterate it. Anyway I'm keeping on struggling with the previous question

Answer (score 2):

It will work out, when you specify the y.position before plotting (see in the examples of ?stat_pvalue_manual):

```
stat.test <- stat.test %>%
  mutate(y.position = c(0.15,0.1,0.05,0,0.05,0))
```

Just adjust the positions to your data.

Answer (score 0):

My solution (for ggplots using geom_bar):

#inherit.aes = FALSE to break link to previous aesthetics

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x,
               y = y)
  
  geom_bar() +
  
  stat_pvalue_manual(inherit.aes = FALSE, #inherit.aes = FALSE
                     stat.test,
                     y.position = c(1,2,3))
```

Got inspired here: https://statisticsglobe.com/r-ggplot2-geom_path-error-fun-object-not-found